# Converting string "0x1A" to sbyte

Tags: c#

I'm getting the exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

at runtime for the following code snippet.

```
string str= "0x1A";

sbyte value= Convert.ToSByte(str);
```

Can anyone help in fixing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also specify what you have already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So what is the exception you are getting? What do you expect this code to do? Please spend some time thinking about your questions and formatting them before posting.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format..

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't post detail like that in comments.

Comment: I've done it for you, but next time please edit (as above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up in the [documentation of ToSByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0hdkwd9(v=vs.110).aspx) under the section **Exceptions** you will find the condition under which this exception is thrown:

> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a **sequence of digits (0 through 9)**.

You value is written in HEX format, meaning to the base of 16. The input string contains not only "**digits (0 through 9)**". For that you will need another overload of this method in which you can specify this.

If you look at this overload of [Convert.ToSByte Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5ss9sbw(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that it:

> Converts the string representation of a number in a **specified base** to an equivalent 8-bit signed integer.

The second parameter is :

> fromBase
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The base of the number in value, which must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.

So specifying the base will releave you from the exception:

```
string str = "0x1A";
sbyte value = Convert.ToSByte(str, 16);
```

Comment: I don't understand why we are telling the OP what their exception is, it's their responsibility to tell us!

Comment: @DavidG you absolutely correct, I was just removing it to replace it with an explanation from the documentation

Answer (score 6):

`Convert.ToSByte` takes an argument `int fromBase` to specify the base you're converting from.
In your case you have to do the following:

```
sbyte s = Convert.ToSByte(str, 16); // s == 26
```

You can read more about different bases (also called radix) in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix).

Comment: Be useful to explain what base this is, why the 16, etc

Comment: I added the corresponding wikipedia article with a list of different bases. This should be sufficient I guess :)